# how to show alert inside an activity group?

Tags: android

I have a tab bar inside my app and to maintain it I have used activity group. On clicking these tabs I have to show a set of activities. My problem is I am not able to show an alert dialog or any other dialogs inside these activities. An error occurs saying "unable to add window". Can anyone tell how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It gives above error because of the Context I was providing to alertdialog builder.

Give:

new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).setMessage(“Hello world”).show();

We just need to call getParent() instead of AlertDialog.Builder(this)